# Как отправить запрос веб-сервису, который в качестве входного параметра использует XDTO?

Tags: 1с, android

День добрый!

Есть 1С, на ней поднят веб-сервис. Который в качестве параметра принимает XDTO пакет. Запрос из 1С к 1С работает. Как запросить 1С из Android? Причем когда делал раньше в качестве входящего в параметра 1С строку, все работает. Отправляю в 1С с android строку, получаю SOAP ответ, разбираю. Но хочется именно xml объекты. Если интересно могу выложить исходники.

Comment: ksoap2-android ее использую для чтения. Как с ее помощью создать объект?

Comment: вручную только. создание биндингов в нем не предусмотрено.

есть альтернатива - [Binding WSDL to Java with JAXB][1].

[1]:http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jaxb.html

Comment: Нашел вот этот материал http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html

Капаю в сторону объекта KvmSerializable

Comment: Да, там как раз и описывается как разбирается ответ и записывается в объект, вручную созданный. Просто есть механизмы в разных средах, которые по WSDL-ссылке сами отстраивают иерархию классов и типов (1С в том числе), в ksoap этого нету.

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с SOAP в андроиде можно воспользоваться [ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/).

StackOverflow: [How to call a .NET Webservice from Android using KSOAP2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052300/how-to-call-a-net-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2).

CodeProject: [Consuming .NET Web Services via the kSOAP library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29305/Consuming-NET-Web-Services-via-the-kSOAP-library).